# MVC/Code First: how to add more tables to the same db context?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using the standard MVC template that comes with VS 2013.  It has a neat membership provider that makes using external logins (Google, Facebook etc) a breeze.  There are also tutorials on how to extend the `IdentityUser` model to add new properties such as date of birth.

I would like to add more tables (of my application) to the already coded database context so as to enjoy the same code first migration features. How do I do it?  The current db context is defined as follows:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you are using asp.net MVC5 identity 2 then ApplicationDbContext already there in IdentityModels.cs .So you can add table (DbSet) like this.

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("ApplicationDbContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
}

public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. My next question: how do I override the Seed method where I can populate some sample rows every time the database is recreated?

Comment: Hi, you can do that by implementing a custom database intitializer and overriding the seed method there. have a look here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx